# Data Reviewer Errors loading batch job

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, batch, data-reviewer

We've recently had one of our GIS Techs create some QA/QC check via data reviewer. However no one seems to be able to use the checks he has created.

We placed the single file .rbj on our shared network 
Our editing is versioned
Using 10.2
Error reads:

> Warning! There was an exception loading the batch job(s). Loading
>   aborted

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This could be related to the installation of the executable. Try the below steps;

1. Make sure that InstallXMLSupport.exe is available in C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\EsriProductionMapping\Desktop10.2\Bin
2. Open the command prompt as Administrator. (Type CMD into Windows Explorer)
3. Set the directory path as: C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\EsriProductionMapping\Desktop10.2\Bin
4. Following is the example for running this utility: InstallXmlSupport.exe /installdirectory:"C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\ArcGISDataReviewer\Desktop10.2\XMLSupport" /Product:Desktop /Version:10.2